# Display records in access db combobox on any text typed by user

Tags: vba, string, ms-access, text, combobox

I am creating an Access .accdb database to get information about company card purchases from personnel in my department.

I have a main form that they will fill out.  Their entries will populate a table, CCPurchForm.  That table combined with a query that includes other tables is used to generate a report that gives all of the information needed for a purchase.

I have a combobox that is used to select the vendor for each purchase.  The Row Source for the combobox is the autonumber ID field and Vendor Name fields of a separate Vendors table.  I have the ID column set to 0” so it does not show. The combobox is limited to the records in the Vendors table.  If a user needs to add a vendor, they have to use another form because I have to have certain vendor information.

Because of the number of vendors, the vendor field needs to filter results as the user types in text.  I would like to have the combobox bring up possible matches based on any string of characters the user types in the combobox, for example if they type in “Bioscience” the combobox will show “Biosciences, Ltd.,” “BD Biosciences,” “New England Biosciences,” etc.  The user then clicks on the correct match and the Vendor Name shows on the form in the combobox and the ID number is stored in the VendorID field of the CCPurchForm table. 
The selected Vendor also populates additional vendor information in a subform on the main form.

I have another combobox that is based on three fields from a Purchase Type table. There is an autonumber ID field for each purchase type, the purchase type code used by my institution, and the purchase type description text.  (I created the ID field to differentiate between sub-types of purchases because my institution lumps them into general categories (e.g. the difference between a purchase of airfare and a purchase of lodging).

I would like users to be able to type in either the institution purchase type code or text to describe their purchase (again, any string of characters) and have the combobox filter results down for them to make a final selection. (Example if the user types “airfare” the combobox brings up every record containing the text “airfare” no matter where it appears in the text or if they type in the institutions purchase code number it brings up all of the records that have that code.) The autonumber ID for their selection should then store in the PurchCodeID field of the CCPurch Form table.

Is it possible to get the comboboxes in my form to function as I have described above?  I’ve searched and searched and can’t find a situation close enough to mine to find a solution.  I am a newbie at VBA, but can function ok with code if I know where to store it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you need to do to get this to work.

1. Create a combo called `cboVendors`
2. In the properties of the combo: Set `Column Count = 2` (ID, Vendors) and `Column Widths = 0cm, 5cm` (change widths accordingly)
3. In the EVENT tab of the properties for `cboVendors` go to `On Key Up` event and click the three dots `...` - a dialog box will show to choose builder - select **Code Builder**
4. Copy the code below:

   ```
   'test number of characters entered - if greater then 2 then assign rowsource
   If Len(Me.cboVendors.Text) > 2 Then

       'set the rowsource to match user search criteria
        Me.cboVendors.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM vendors WHERE vendors LIKE '*" & Me.cboVendors.Text & "*'"

       'show the search in real-time
        Me.cboVendors.Dropdown
   Else
       'set to no
        Me.cboVendors.RowSource = ""
   End If
   ```

Your result should look something like this:

[image: Your result should look something like this:]

You can do the same for your other combo search too.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Justin.  Things came up that prevented me from working on this project for several weeks, I was able to finally try your solution. I created the combo box and followed the wizard to have it store the vendor ID and put in the code you specified. When I go to form view, it doesn't appear to be working correctly.  No matter what I type in, I get a blank dropdown box.   
I tried making an adjustment “vendors” in your code ' to match the field name in the Vendors table of my db, “strVendor”
I’m not sure what I did incorrectly.  I would appreciate any additional help.