# Filter as you type combo box me.recordsource

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I can upload a file if someone tells me how.

Need help replicating a filter as you type on a combo box that is being used at the record level.  Example:  Instead of having an open text box for the prefix (e.g. Mr. Mrs. Ms. Dr.), I'm using a combo box that looks up from a reference table.  I want to be able to type the letter "r" in the combo box and have it filter out Ms. and showing the remaining values.  Once I make a selection store the selected value in the Name table.

Issue:  When I add a new value in Combo4 the other rows above clear out if they don't match the value I just typed into the cell.  Something likely with the RowSource in the below formula.  Do I have something out of sequence or a flawed formula?

What I think I'm trying to do:
  1) If Prefix value populated w/ value in t_Name THEN show the matching value in t_ref_Prefix
  2) If Combo4 is Blank / Null THEN then open Combo4 and show all values in t_ref_Prefix so a value can be selected.
  3) If user is typing text into Combo4 THEN filter on change using * on both sides of the typed value.

```css
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Combo4_Change()
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48133260/display-records-in-access-db-combobox-on-any-text-typed-by-user
'test number of characters entered - if greater then 0 then assign rowsource
    
If Len(Me.Combo4.Text) > 0 Then
    'set the rowsource to match user search criteria
     Me.Combo4.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM t_ref_Prefix WHERE Prefix LIKE '*" & Me.Combo4.Text & "*'"
    'show the search in real-time
     Me.Combo4.Dropdown
Else
    'set to no
     Me.Combo4.RowSource = "SELECT t_ref_Prefix.auto, t_ref_Prefix.prefix, t_ref_Prefix.sort FROM _    
       t_ref_Prefix ORDER BY t_ref_Prefix.sort, t_ref_Prefix.prefix"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

> Combo4.AutoExpand =  False

This will do it.